# Rails 3 + Devise - Log-in user can't open page to change password

Tags: ruby, devise, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I use Rails 3 application with `devise`, `simple form` and `haml` gems. Also my application supports few locales. I created simple link on my home page:

```
%p
  = link_to "Change pass", edit_user_password_path
```

App shows this link for everyone (just to test it). But i founded that non log-in user can open this link. But when log-in user opens this link then system tells that:

```
You are already signed in.
```

I can't figure what i'm doing wrong.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

My routes:

```
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]                                          

    root :to => 'pages#home'
  end

  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" }
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

Also i commented few lines in **views/devise/shared/_links.haml**

```
- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations'
  / = link_to t(".sign_up_link"), new_registration_path(resource_name)
  / %br/
```

Because i don't want to allow users to register and see the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`edit_user_password_path` is used by the `password_controller` in Devise for when a user needs to reset their password. I think what you are looking for is the `edit_user_registration_path` . This will take the user to edit action of the `registrations_controller` where they can modify their email address and password. This is default Devise behavior.

If you would like to provide something a little more custom, you can read a tutorial on the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) on how to provide custom password change functionality.

Also take note, that when a user follows `edit_user_registration_path` there is an option for them to cancel their account that you may want to remove from the view, or use the custom approach to avoid this unwanted functionality.

Comment: It is strange. I tried to use `edit_user_registration_path` in my view but Rails generates `undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration_path'`.

Comment: You need to remove the `:skip => [:registrations]` for that path to be active, or use the custom strategy provided by the Wiki article.